# Printing data from database to index page

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make custom website for news, just for learning, and i was wondering, how can i print data from database?

So there is news name, news text, news author and news date, my question is how can i print that to index page and when somebody click on some of that news in link looks like ?id=1.

EDITED:

```
$squery = "SELECT * FROM vesti";
$rsquery = mysqli_query($db,$squery);

while($svevesti = mysqli_fetch_asssoc($rsquery){

    // action here
}
```

Thanks for Your time.

Comment: Can you post code with your attempt.

Comment: I didnt attempt because i dont know how, and on google i cant find anything cause i dont how to google that...
This is where im stucked at
`$squery = "SELECT * FROM vesti";
$rsquery = mysqli_query($db,$squery);

while($svevesti = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsquery)){
  // action should go here, right?

}`

Comment: Add more info by editing the question, please, not in comments. (Especially code.) And yes, action should go there. :)

Comment: Put a link `<a href=..` with an identifier to the record you want inside the `fetch`. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662218/php-mysql-how-to-auto-generate-delete-link-for-a-row-in-an-already-auto-genera/33662367#33662367 and instead of `delete` use `select` (add the columns as well).

Comment: I edited, can i get some help now, or u still gonna talk about other stuff rather than answering the real question? @Don'tPanic ?

Comment: I don't know, what other stuff would you like to talk about?

Comment: @chris85 i tryed it and it worked, thank you a lot.

Comment: @Don'tPanic hmm, should i delete comment where i commented wrong?